Issue with deploying NextJS app that uses embedded Spline component
Using react-spline library to render embedded Spline JSX element like this:
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Spline = dynamic(() => import("@splinetool/react-spline"), {
    ssr: false,
});

const DroidRender = () => {
    return (
        <Spline scene="my-spline-url" />
    );
};

export default DroidRender;

Currently seeing this error when trying to deploying on Vercel:
Creating an optimized production build ...
Failed to compile.

./components/DroidRender.jsx
Module not found: Package path . is not exported from package (path)/node_modules/@splinetool/react-spline (see exports field in (path)/node_modules/@splinetool/react-spline/package.json)

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Checked the package.json for react-spline and these are the first 20 lines:
 "name": "@splinetool/react-spline",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.3.0",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "type": "module",
  "react-native": "./dist/react-spline.js",
  "types": "./dist/Spline.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/Spline.d.ts",
      "import": "./dist/react-spline.js"
    },
    "./next": {
      "types": "./dist/next/SplineNext.d.ts",
      "import": "./dist/react-spline-next.js"
    }
  },

...more json content

Tried to change the import to server-side rendering (set ssr = true).
Tried using /next entry point shown in package.json export.
Neither worked.
Any ideas on how I could fix this error?
Would love to deploy this app on Vercel if at all possible.
